# Time Complexity of Subsets problem solution

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

I would like to verify the space and time complexity of my solution to [subsets](https://leetcode.com/problems/subsets/) problem on leetcode. The space complexity is O(N) due to stack space. The time complexity is O(2^N) as the work on each ith level is adding 2^i elements to the list. So summing 2^i from 0 to N yields O(2^N). Am I correct? I am not sure because the 3 official solutions have time complexity O(N*2^N).

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {
    // Space Complexity: O(N) 
    // Time Complexity: 2^0 + 2^1 + ... + 2^N = O(2^N) 
    public List<List<Integer>> subsets(int[] nums) {
        List<List<Integer>> subsets = new ArrayList<>();
        subsets.add(List.of());
        subsetsHelper(nums, 0, subsets);
        return subsets;
    }

    private void subsetsHelper(int[] nums, int index, List<List<Integer>> subsets) {
        if (index >= nums.length) return;
        int current = nums[index];
        int initialSize = subsets.size();
        for (int i = 0; i < initialSize; i++) {
            var list = subsets.get(i);
            var listCopy = new ArrayList<>(list);
            listCopy.add(current);
            subsets.add(listCopy);
        }
        subsetsHelper(nums, index + 1, subsets);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Solution solution = new Solution();
        System.out.println(solution.subsets(new int[]{0, 1, 2}));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out why it's 2^N times N.

For `subsetsHelper()`, at `i`th level, the number of subsets is `2^(i-1)`. And the size of each subsetList in it is `O(N)`.  As I double the size of each sub subsetList (from `list` to `listCopy` in code) in `subsetsHelper()` its time complexity is `O(N*2^i)`.

And since the function is called N times, the time complexity of `subsets()` is `O(N*(2^0 +...+2^(N-1)) = O(N*2^N)`

Answer (score 0):

The backtracking part takes (2^N) for tree generation and the N is from traversing the given array from 1 t0 N.